# Magento 1.9 Get post data from contact form in a view

Tags: magento-1.9, post-data

I'm trying to get a success message on the contact page. When the form is send i want to show the message. So i need the post data from the form. I tried this:

```
$postdata = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost('email');
```

And

```
$postdata = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
```

And

```
$postdata = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

But i don't get the post data

I want to display a success message, i thought that when i have the post data in the view i can make a if statment in the view to show the success message

Comment: you mean success notification?

Comment: I don't use the default form but a extension and if i have a post value of 1 of the input fields than i want to show a success message @QaisarSatti

Comment: Can you edit your answer and explain the logic you are after? Are you after manipulating post data, or creating success messages?

Comment: I don't want to manipulate the post data, i just want to show a success message @Mayers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the formular is send to actionA, which redirects to actionB and you try to get the data in actionB, this is not possible. You need to save them somewhere, e.g. in the session.